# What is the time complexity of this python function which includes slice operations?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am learning python slice operations and I decided to write a simple function that iterates through a string with a window of size k and adds the window to the dictionary along with its frequency. So for example if the string input is "abab" and k is 2, the dictionary will contain "ab:2" and "ba:1".

I am confused what will be the time complexity of this function:

In the code, s is input string and k is window size.

```
def test_func(s, k):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(s) - k + 1):
        sub_str = s[i:i+k]
        if sub_str in d:
            d[sub_str] += 1
        else:
            d[sub_str] = 1
    return d
```

I am thinking that time complexity of it will be O(n * k) and space complexity of it will be O(n) where n is size of list and k is size of window but I am not sure if it is right. Can you please review the function and let me know if my analysis is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Time and space are both `O(n*k)`

Comment: @Barmar I fail to see how the space complexity is *O(n x k)*. The two variables for storing the sliced string and a dictionary of frequencies require only space proportional to the window size and the number of distinct substrings, respectively. The size of the string itself is never a factor in the space complexity.

Comment: If there are no duplicate slices, there will be `n*k` different keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar Well yes but that's the worst case scenario. Usually when asked without further qualification complexity is meant to refer to the average case.

Comment: The average case is that half the slices are unique. Dividing by a constant doesn't change big-O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and space should both be `O(n*k)`.

Looking up a dictionary key of size `k` is `O(k)` because you have to hash `k`, which requires reading all the characters of `k`. While we often treat dictionary and set lookup as amortized constant time, I don't think we can use that simplification when the dictionary key size is one of the parameters.

Since you do these lookups `O(n)` times, the time complexity is `O(n*k)`.

Since all the keys have to be stored in the dictionary, and the worst case is that there are no duplicate slices, the dictionary may have to contain `n*k` keys.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Is it possible to reduce the time complexity for this function to O(n)?

Comment: I don't think so. You could use your own hash function that hashes a fixed number of characters, but that's likely to increase collisions, resulting in worse performance of the hash table. There's no free lunch.